# Merging PyOpenGL with Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, tkinter, pyopengl

## PyOpen GL with Tkinter

Hey guys how can I implement OpenGL into tkinter?
Should i use Pygame? But when I do so - only `glClear(...)` works.
I've heard about OpenGL.Tk but the problem is that when i want to import it, python gives me the following exception:

[image: error]

## And here is my code I've written

```
import csv
from tkinter import *
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.Tk import *
import os
from numpy import *


root = Tk() 


canvas = Frame(root,width=500,height=500).pack()

os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(canvas.winfo_id())
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'

pygame.init() 
pygame.display.set_mode((500,500), OPENGL|DOUBLEBUF) 

gluOrtho2D(-10,10,-10,10)

while True:

    glClearColor(0.2,0.2,0.2,1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glBegin(GL_POINTS)
    glColor3f(1,1,1)
    glVertex2f(0,0)
    glEnd()


    root.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(30)
```

Have you got any idea how can I make this working?
I've spent most of the time today to search for it...

Comment: when I use PyGame - only the following command works:
glClear() (is a built-in OpenGL command which clears canvas basiacally)

I installed them both using PIP

Comment: No i did not... are you sure this can help? I mean.. pip should use the original source of modules...

Comment: It would appear that not all the code is compatible with Python 3 (`sys.maxint` does not exist in Python 3). You could try to edit the file in which the error occurs for compatibility with Python 3.